# Retroactively adding the primary key to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wrote a migration for a join model which looks like:

```
  create_table "project_memberships", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "id"
  end
```

I want to forcibly create ids now.  Must I drop the table and recreate it or can I write a migration removing this constraint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a primary key to a table in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644509/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-table-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks for the note, @ABMagil.  I want to leave this question here because in my case there was already an `id` column (which is not true in your link).  However, I am open to closing it if this isn't a significant difference to the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small amount of googling... http://thinkwhere.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/adding-a-primary-key-id-to-table-in-rails/

Generate a empty migration:

```
rails generate migration AddIdToProjectMemberships
```

and fill it in with:

```
def change
    add_column :project_memberships, :id, :primary_key
end
```

Also there was a question like this before.. [how to add a primary key to a table in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644509/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-table-in-rails)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to use the term primary key in my searches.  Thanks!