# How to change primary key in rails migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

I need to migrate an old mysql table like this:

```
Products
  name (string, primary_key)
```

to this schema:

```
Products
  id (integer, primary_key, auto_generated)
  name (unique)
```

I need the Products.id values populated in the new table.
How can i write the rails migration file? I am using Rails 3.2.7

I have 2 problems now:
1. I can't find a method to remove primary key in ActiveRecord::Migration
2. I don't know how to generate values for newly added primary key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a primary key to a table in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644509/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-table-in-rails)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could execute arbitrary SQL in your migration:

```
execute "ALTER TABLE `products` DROP PRIMARY KEY"
```

and then add the new column:

```
add_column :products, :id, :primary_key
```

See:

[Remove Primary Key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111291/remove-primary-key-in-mysql)

[how to add a primary key to a table in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644509/how-to-add-a-primary-key-to-a-table-in-rails)

http://thinkwhere.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/adding-a-primary-key-id-to-table-in-rails/

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Answer (score 17):

If you're on Postgresql, the syntax is slightly different.

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP CONSTRAINT <table_name>_pkey;
```