# Rails model user ID PG ERROR: NotNullViolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, postgresql-9.3

I'm using rails 4, postgres 9.3 and devise, and at the moment of sign up an user, I'm getting the error of :

```
    PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: the null value for column « usuario_id » violates the constraint not null.
```

The primary key or ID of the table or model usuario is usuario_id and it's an integer.

I understand that it violates de constraint, but how can I autoincrement the ID without entering it through the sign up form?

I didn't do the migration 'cause it's unnecessary because I already have the tables in postgres. The only columns that I add are the devise ones. Anyway this is the table from postgresql.

```
                           Tabla «public.usuario»
    Column         |            Type            |                  Modifiers                   
------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------
usuario_id             | integer                     | not null
comuna_id              | integer                     | not null
usuario_nombre         | character(256)              | 
usuario_apellidopat    | character(256)              | 
usuario_apellidomat    | character(256)              | 
usuario_rut            | character varying(1024)     | 
email                  | character varying(1024)     | 
usuario_nombre_usuario | character(256)              | 
password               | character varying(128)      | 
usuario_vip            | boolean                     | 
usuario_calle          | character varying(128)      | 
usuario_numero_calle   | smallint                    | 
usuario_villa          | character varying(128)      | 
usuario_numero_depto   | smallint                    | 
usuario_bloque         | smallint                    | 
encrypted_password     | character varying(255)      | not null valor por omisión      
reset_password_token   | character varying(255)      | 
reset_password_sent_at | timestamp without time zone | 
remember_created_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
sign_in_count          | integer                     | not null valor por omisión 0
current_sign_in_at     | timestamp without time zone | 
last_sign_in_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
current_sign_in_ip     | character varying(255)      | 
last_sign_in_ip        | character varying(255)      | 
confirmation_token     | character varying(255)      | 
confirmed_at           | timestamp without time zone | 
confirmation_sent_at   | timestamp without time zone | 
unconfirmed_email      | character varying(255)      | 
 Índexes:
"pk_usuario" PRIMARY KEY, btree (usuario_id)
"index_usuario_on_reset_password_token" UNIQUE, btree (reset_password_token)
"usuario_pk" UNIQUE, btree (usuario_id)
"relationship_34_fk" btree (comuna_id)
Foreign key constraints:
"fk_usuario_relations_comuna" FOREIGN KEY (comuna_id) REFERENCES comuna(comuna_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
Referenced by:
TABLE "compra_remate" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_r_relations_usuario" FOREIGN KEY (usu_usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "compra_remate" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_r_relations_usuario2" FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "compra_venta_especial" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_v_relations_usuario" FOREIGN KEY (usu_usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "compra_venta_normal" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_v_relations_usuario" FOREIGN KEY (usu_usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "compra_venta_especial" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_v_relations_usuario2" FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "compra_venta_normal" CONSTRAINT "fk_compra_v_relations_usuario2" FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "notificacion" CONSTRAINT "fk_notifica_relations_usuario" FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
TABLE "prod_of_nec" CONSTRAINT "fk_prod_of__relations_usuario" FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES u:
```

Comment: Can we see the migration you did for the `usuario_id` column?

Answer (score 1):

First, in your User model migration, did change the primary key for the user table to be `usuario_id`? See the following Stackoverflow question:

- [How to change primary key in rails migration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622303/how-to-change-primary-key-in-rails-migration-file)

Second, did you make sure that you overrode the naming convention for the primary key in your ActiveRecord models?

Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "usuario_id"
end
```

See the following [section in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions) for more details.

Comment: I didn't do the migration, because It's unnecessary because I already have the tables in postgresql.

I just did the scaffold but I delete the migration files because they are unnecessary.

Second, yes, I did the self.primary_key = "usuario_id"

Comment: Hm interesting. Could you also post the model code?